# How to identify a Button or title bar Close button click raised Window_Close event in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have 3 WPF Forms namely MainWindow, SettingWindow and FinalWindow. I have a FinalButton in the SettingWindow when I click on the button I want to clone the current SettingWindows and want to open the FinalWindow. Similarly when I click on the Close button in the title bar, I want to close the current form and open the MainWindow. But I have been facing a problem and the problem is when I click on the Close button in the title bar or click on ButtonFinal, in both cases the MainWindow is opened and to avoid this I have to put a conditon in the closing event to know which button raised the event. I didn't get the actual solution to the problem. Could you please help me to solve the problem.

```
private void ButtonFinal_Click(object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FinalWindow finalWindow = new FinalWindow();
    finalWindow.Show();
    this.Close();
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag in the `ButtonFinal_Click` event handler and check this flag in the `Closing` event handler, e.g.:

```
private bool _closedByButton;
private void ButtonFinal_Click(object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FinalWindow finalWindow = new FinalWindow();
    finalWindow.Show();
    _closedByButton = true;
    this.Close();
    _closedByButton = false;
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_closedByButton)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```